# Error Deploying an Android App Using Google Maps API

Tags: java, android, google-maps, eclipse-adt

I'm attempting to run an Android app, that makes use of Google's map API, onto the Android simulator via the Eclipse plugin.

Even though I have the Google APIs installed, when I created my initial project, the links to the API jars where not included. So I copied maps.jar from `android-sdk-linux/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-16/libs` into my project's libs folder, and that resolved all the reference errors.

However, when I go to "Run" (Ctrl+F11) my app on the simulator, it fails with the error `Package com.mydomain.myapp requires unavailable shared library com.google.android.maps; failing!`

I have several other jars in my libs folder, and I'm not getting any errors for those. Why isn't it copying over the maps.jar? How do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you targeting the Google APIs when you create your project? Try this:

1. Right-click your project in the Package Explorer
2. Click on "Properties".
3. Click on the "Android" tab
4. Check the appropriate "Google API"
5. Apply changes and see if it works.

Comment: Yep, I had to do this as well as modify my virtual device like Hesham mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

Do what Yawus said, then do this: Click on AVD Manager, then highlight your virtual device and click edit, then change the Target to `Google APIs (Google Inc.) - API Level XX`.

Comment: Ah, that could be it. I forgot that your emulator had to target the proper API too.

Comment: He has to check both things anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a simulator that has the google libraries in it.  You can't add it to your app.  If you look, when you created the virtual device you can either pick versions that have or don;t have Google APIs in them.